# Windows can't find network adapter

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, network-adapter

**Problem:**
Did you check the device manager? Yep, it doesn't show up there. At Device Manager did you use Action -> Scan? Yep, didn't make Qualcomm Atheros show up. Used Powershell command get-netadapter? Yep, nothing showed up. I have a Lenovo, and on it there's a D: partition where there's installs for the drivers that came with the laptop. I started the setup.exe file. I tried to repair it, I uninstalled it and then re-install. It had no change. I assume the drivers are properly installed but there's no point if it can't detect the adapter.

Anyone can help me here?

The adapter is not detached / broken because my Ubuntu partition can detect it and is using it to connect to networks wirelessly. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it fixed itself but I let my laptop's battery deplete completely, and the next time it booted it started completing the Window Updates. After it was finished my Windows wireless worked again.